# Dynamically clean target CSS selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am using Ruby and Nokogiri to get contents held within certain tags targeted by their CSS selectors.

However, I am running into an issue where the target tag has a unique product ID appended to the end of the CSS ID name.

Example:

```
a#exampleIdNameB000AQ40M8B00JYWUHO4
```

In my script, I am trying to scrape this information for multiple products, so this ID is going to change each time and is breaking the scrape.

Specifically, I am getting the contents within the tags like so:

```
remove_html_tags(doc.css(html).to_s.strip)
```

where the HTML will that it is searching for is `a#exampleIdName`.

Is there a way to tell Nokogiri to treat `a#exampleIdNameB000AQ40M8B00JYWUHO4` found in the document the same as:

```
a#examplIdName
```

so I can match for all the product pages?

Comment: You need to provide a small HTML sample for your input, and an example of the output format you need, along with a reasonable example of the code you're using. Doing what you want isn't hard, but it wastes our time having to come up with the input data, time we can use helping others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you can search by attribute prefix:

```
require "nokogiri"

html = "<div id=foo123>A</div> <div id=foo456>B</div> <div id=bar123>C</div>"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
p doc.css("div[id^=foo]").map(&:text)  # ["A", "B"]
```

Comment: I'd use the prefix method to search the IDs. It'll always find the current ones in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to approach this is to use classes instead of ID. If these elements do not have a common class, you could use regex to strip the unwanted part of the ID attribute before parsing them via nokogiri.

Use Regex to replace `a#exampleIdNameB000AQ40M8B00JYWUHO4` with `a#examplIdName` in your document.

Comment: What if the HTML has no classes? Show example code of how you'd preprocess the file.